# How to calculate super amount?

Tags: income-tax, australia, superannuation

What is the actual super amount if it is $2000 iclusive super? My friend says $190 is the super amount. I couldn't understand how?

Comment: $190 is 9.5% of $2000.  Does that percentage ring a bell?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.